# Freeform subview’s width doesn’t expand to device screen size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout

I'm trying to add a music miniplayer view controller to a container UITabBarVC. The music miniplayer view controller is a freeform storyboard file. I am implementing the file as follows:

```
 self.miniPlayerViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(with: MiniPlayerViewController.identifier)
 self.miniPlayerViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.customBottomOffset, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 92)
```

This exists in a function which I execute in viewDidLoad().

On larger devices, such as an iPhone 8 Plus (below), the miniplayer doesn't expand to fit the screen's width despite me using UIScreen.main.bounds.width as the width parameter. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

[image]

**Update**
Tried setting View width to Now Playing View width, but didn’t help the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this was due to how I was rounding the corners of the miniplayer. Guess executing this code under didSet did not allow the view to actually register the size of the screen:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var nowPlayingView: UIView! {
    didSet {
        nowPlayingView.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 20.0)
    }
}
```

I would appreciate if anyone could please explain this further.